# Fast way of saving many images with matplotlib and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I noticed that there is a big performance gap between the following two solutions to load and save images with matplotlib. Can anyone explain why, and what is the best (and fastest) way to save images in a python for loop?

**Implementation 1:**
create a figure outside the for loop, update what is displayed and then save.

```
fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30, 20))  # <--------

# list_of_fnames is just a list of file names
for k, fname in enumerate(list_of_fnames):
    with Image.open(fname) as img:
        x = np.array(img)

    y = process_image_fn1(x)
    z = process_image_fn2(x)

    a[0].imshow(x)
    a[1].imshow(y)
    a[2].imshow(z)

    output_filename = f'results_{k}.png'
    plt.savefig(output_filename, dpi=320, format='png', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

**Implementation 2:**
create a figure inside the for loop, save it, finally destroy it.

```
# list_of_fnames is just a list of file names
for k, fname in enumerate(list_of_fnames):
    with Image.open(fname) as img:
        x = np.array(img)

    y = process_image_fn1(x)
    z = process_image_fn2(x)

    fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30, 20))  # <--------
    a[0].imshow(x)
    a[1].imshow(y)
    a[2].imshow(z)

    output_filename = f'results_{k}.png'
    plt.savefig(output_filename, dpi=320, format='png', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

    plt.close()  # <--------
```

Comment: I imagine the first one is very slow as the saved files get larger and larger.  You are adding more and more images to each subplot each loop iteration.

Comment: I had the same suspect. Is there any alternative to closing and creating a new figure at each iteration of the for loop? I mean, is there any way of re-using the same figure (i.e. the output of `plt.subplots`) without making larger the files that I save?

Comment: You can clear the axes or clear the figure each loop

Answer (score 2):

The first option could be improved in a couple of ways.

1. removing the previously plotted AxesImages (from `imshow`), so that you don't keep increasing the number of plotted images on the axes

```
fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30, 20))  # <--------

# list_of_fnames is just a list of file names
for k, fname in enumerate(list_of_fnames):

    for ax in a:
        ax.images.pop()

    with Image.open(fname) as img:
        x = np.array(img)

    y = process_image_fn1(x)
    z = process_image_fn2(x)

    a[0].imshow(x)
    a[1].imshow(y)
    a[2].imshow(z)

    output_filename = f'results_{k}.png'
    plt.savefig(output_filename, dpi=320, format='png', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

2. alternatively, create the AxesImages once per axes, then rather than replot them each iteration, use `.set_array()` to change what is plotted on the AxesImage

```
fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30, 20))  # <--------

# list_of_fnames is just a list of file names
for k, fname in enumerate(list_of_fnames):
    with Image.open(fname) as img:
        x = np.array(img)

    y = process_image_fn1(x)
    z = process_image_fn2(x)

    if k == 0:
        im0 = a[0].imshow(x)
        im1 = a[1].imshow(y)
        im2 = a[2].imshow(z)
    else:
        im0.set_array(x)
        im1.set_array(y)
        im2.set_array(z)

    output_filename = f'results_{k}.png'
    plt.savefig(output_filename, dpi=320, format='png', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: the first solution doesn't seem to work for me